# Question about Folland PDE book Chapter 8

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

Page 284-285:

Let $\Omega\subset {\mathbb R}^n$ be a domain. 
Let $a(x, \xi, y)$ be an "amplitude", i.e. a smooth function on $\Omega\times{\mathbb R}^n\times\Omega$ so that there is $m$, and for any compact set $B\subset\Omega$, one has 
$$
\sup_{x, y\in B}|D_x^\beta D_y^\gamma D_\xi^\alpha a(x, \xi, y)|\leq C_{\alpha, \beta,\gamma, B}(1+|\xi|)^{m-|\alpha|}.
$$
Then one can define an operator $P_a$ on $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$:
$$
P_au(x)=\int_{{\mathbb R}^n}\int_\Omega e^{(x-y)\xi i}a(x, \xi, y)u(y)dy d\xi.
$$
Then in equation (8.23) Folland proceed to say that the Schwartz kernel of $P_a$ is 
$$
K(x, y)=a_2^\vee(x, x-y, y).
$$

My question is, how to make sense of this? As I understand, $a_2^\vee$ is a distribution on $\Omega\times{\mathbb R}^n\times \Omega$ defined as 
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle a_2^\vee, \varphi\rangle
=&\int_\Omega\int_{{\mathbb R}^n}\int_\Omega a(x,\xi, y) \varphi_2^\vee(x, \xi, y)dxd\xi dy\\
=&\int_\Omega\int_{{\mathbb R}^n}\int_\Omega a(x,\xi, y) 
\Big[\int_{{\mathbb R}^n} e^{\eta\xi i}\varphi(x, \eta, y)d\eta\Big]
dxd\xi dy.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus the kernel $K$ seems to be restricting the above $a_2^\vee$ to the hyperplane $\xi=x-y$ in $\Omega\times{\mathbb R}^n\times\Omega$. So how to justify this? Is this way of writing $K$ is just a convenient notation?

Comment: For fixed $x,y$ observe that if $a(x,\xi,y)$ is a Schwartz function in $\xi$ and has compact $x$-support as well as compact $y$-support then rewrite the integral as 

$\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{i(x-y)\xi}a(x,\xi,y)u(y)dxidxdy=\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega} a^\vee (x,x-y,y) u(y)dx dy$

Here $a^{\vee}(x,x-y,y)$ deontes the inverse Fourier transform in the fiber variable at the point $x-y$